# How to find named entity relationship

Tags: python, spacy

I was doing named entity relationship from the text of a book. I have done the Recognition using "spaCy" using its module "en_core_web_sm" as:

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
def NamedEntityRecognition(Text):
    doc = nlp(Text)
    list1 = []
    for ent in doc.ents:
        if ent.label_=='PERSON':
            list1.append((ent.text, ent.label_))
    return list1
```

I only wanted to find the PERSONS from it. Now I wish to find the relationship between different persons (How one person is related to another person, like "is a father of", "is a brother of" kind of relationships) but I don't have any idea about how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are referring to *Relation Extraction*.

What relationship between the entity "person" you seek to find out? Answering that question, and depending on your task you could customize your search.

In general, you should have a look [here](https://medium.com/@andreasherman/different-ways-of-doing-relation-extraction-from-text-7362b4c3169e) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260212/nlp-to-find-relationship-between-entities) if you haven't done that so far.

I hope those help with your problem.